# Can I say 'I've splurged on another lipstick, provided that I have a bunch of them?'

Tags: british-english

Can 'provided that' be used here? Is it okay?

Comment: What do you think that 'provided that' should mean in this context?

Comment: like 'I have a lot of stuff like that so why I buy another one'

Comment: Hello and welcome to the ELU. This site encourages users to show what they have found in the research they did to find an answer to their question. Have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to better understand how to edit your question.